# Does CrateDB have Mechanism for expiring old data？

Tags: crate, cratedb

since the data may become huge , currently, i can only use delete partitions to delete old metircs, does CrateDB have Mechanism for expiring old data？

Answer (score 0):

No CrateDB does not support that currently. Feel free to open a feature request on github including some details/use-cases.